# How to write in SQL Server database in this case?

Tags: python, sql, sql-server

I have two conditions :

```
list=['1','14','57','05','7','254','05']

y=10

for x in list :

  if x='05':
    cursor.execute('''Insert into table (code) values (?) ''', y)
  else : 
    cursor.execute('''Insert into table (code) values (?) ''', y+1)
```

But all I find in my table is 10 when I should have 11 twice.

Comment: `Insert into table` is going to produce a syntax error. `TABLE` is a reserved keyword.

Answer (score 1):

can you please frame the question correctly? And kindly add little more details like how is us result looking like and how do you expect it to be

Two things first:

is you are using the variable name as 'list', its incorrect use another name

second:

the condition should be if x =='05' and not x='05'